# React.js returns blank page after npm start

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently following a YouTuber who has kindly uploaded his codebase to [here](https://github.com/briancodex/react-website-v1/tree/master). I have been following his video closely, but for some reason when I type in npm start in my console I get the project compiling successfully, but nothing appears in the browser. I have tried restarting numerous times, but to no avail and as I'm new to React.js I don't know how to stat debugging this app. My buggy branch is [here](https://github.com/julianmoors/react-travel/tree/bug). Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
I've narrowed the bug to the Button.js component, but I'm not sure why the commented out code isn't working.

```
// import React from 'react';
// import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
// import './Button.css';

// const STYLES = ['btn__primary', 'btn__outline'];
// const SIZES = ['btn__medium', 'btn__large'];

// export const Button = ({
//   children,
//   type,
//   onClick,
//   buttonStyle,
//   buttonSize
// }) => {
//   const checkButtonStyle = STYLES.includes(buttonStyle) ? buttonStyle : STYLES[0];
//   const checkButtonSize = SIZES.includes(buttonSize) ? buttonSize : SIZES[0];

//   return (
//     <Link to='/' className='btn__mobile'>
//       <Button
//         className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}`}
//         onClick={onClick}
//         type={type}
//       >
//       {children}
//       </Button>
//     </Link>
//   );
// };

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Button.css';

export function Button() {
  return (
    <Link to='sign-up'>
      <button className='btn'>Sign Up</button>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

Comment: I cloned your project and it starts fine for me without any modifications. Do you have changes that aren't in the github repo? When you say "nothing appears in the browser" do you mean you just see a blank page at [http://localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000)? If you open the browser's dev tools do you see any errors in the console? Have you tried reinstalling node_modules?

Comment: I've tried reinstalling node_modules, but the project just hangs

Comment: I've deployed the app to firebase using this [url](https://travel-d6f72.web.app)

Answer (score 1):

Are you on localhost:3000 in the browser? React runs on port 3000. Confirm that you are at that address in your browser and try to run npm start again in the correct directory where you created your react-app.

Comment: I'm on http://localhost:3000, but the app just hangs

Comment: So on localhost:3000 the browser page is blank white? Also do you have the react app running? Is there any errors in the dev tools? If so what does the error say?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was trying to call the Button component from within itself with the following code:

```
//       <Button
//         className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}`}
//         onClick={onClick}
//         type={type}
//       >
//       {children}
//       </Button>
```

The Button component should be the  HTML element like so:

```
//       <button
//         className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}`}
//         onClick={onClick}
//         type={type}
//       >
//       {children}
//       </button>
```